# How to get the current text from a UILabel outlet in another class?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5

I have a basic calculator app with a label, some numeric buttons, and some simple operatin buttons. In this app, on the bottom of the screen, the top of another view(AdvancedView) is showing and there is a button on that, and when clicked, the subview slides up to the bottom of the UILabel. I'm able to access the current text in the UILabel from the CalcViewController class because there's an outlet:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *display;
```

in the .h simply by calling:

```
self.display.text
```

But i have a squareRoot button in my AdvancedView (the view that slides up) that also needs access to the UILabel text. How can I both get and set the UILabel text from another class?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
NSString *text = nil;
UIViewController *otherViewController;

for (UIView *view in [otherViewController.view subviews])
{
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
    {
         UILabel *label = (UILabel *) view;
         text = label.text;
         break;
    }
}

if (text == nil)
{
     NSLog(@"Hmm, couldn't find the view...");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to  `@synthesize` your text as well

```
 @synthesize display
```

then in the file you want to use it in import the file you made the label in and then give it a pointer to that class. (in the new .h file)

```
 CalcViewController*  calcViewController;
```

then inside your code you would do:

```
 calcViewController.display.text;
```

Comment: Does this only apply for subclasses? Because I'm trying from a completely different class which is actually a subclass of UIVew. Anyways, Ive doing like what your say and cant seem to access the label. In my NSLog it's printing 0.0000 when I call the label with number typed in it.